# ros2 commandline service call

Tags: ros, ros2, call-service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What's the correct syntax for performing a service call from the command line in ROS2 ?

Consider the following service, defined in `example_interfaces` package

AddTwoInts.srv

```
int a
int b
---
int c
```

Assuming that the server is called `"add_two_ints"`

I managed to pass one argument to the service call in the following way

```
$ ros2 service call /add_two_ints example_interfaces/AddTwoInts "a: '1'"        
requester: making request: example_interfaces.srv.AddTwoInts_Request(a=1, b=0)
```

How to pass also the second argument ?

These are not working

```
$ ros2 service call /add_two_ints example_interfaces/AddTwoInts "a: '1'b:'2'"
$ ros2 service call /add_two_ints example_interfaces/AddTwoInts "a: '1' b:'2'"
$ ros2 service call /add_two_ints example_interfaces/AddTwoInts "a: '1', b:'2'"
$ ros2 service call /add_two_ints example_interfaces/AddTwoInts "a:'1'" "b:'2'"
$ ros2 service call /add_two_ints example_interfaces/AddTwoInts "a:'1'", "b:'2'"
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302192/ros2-commandline-service-call/) by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1322 on 2018-08-31

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to pass a string which is valid YAML, e.g.:

```
ros2 service call /add_two_ints example_interfaces/AddTwoInts "{a: 1, b: 2}"
```

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3